# When do we need to establish signal function again inside a signal handler?

Tags: c, linux, signals, pause

I've got a simple program under linux and it works well:

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
void fStop(int signo){
    printf("Hup\n");
}
int main(){
    signal(SIGHUP,fStop);
    for(;;){
        pause();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It runs and waits for signals. Each time I send "kill -1 xxx" to it, it prints a "Hup" line. OK

But my questions are:

> 1. I found if I remove the "for" loop, seems the pause() won't work after receiving SIGHUP signal. Does it mean that signal will interupt any kind of sleep and suspension functions?
> 2. In some linux programs, I see people re-estbalish signal function inside a signal handler like:

```
void fStop((int signo){
     printf("Hup\n");
     signal(SIGHUP,fStop);//When is this necessary?
}
```

Just a bit confused how linux signal handler should be designed, when to re-establish handler, depends on different signals?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that signal will inter[r]upt any kind of sleep and suspension functions?

Probably not *all*, but it interrupts `pause()`, yes.

From [`pause()`'s documentation (Linux)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> `pause()` returns only when a signal was caught and the signal-catching
>          function returned.  In this case, `pause()` returns -1, and `errno` is
>          set to `EINTR`.